# A problem with Presentations from Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-slides

Today, when I was run SlidesApp batchUpdate, the Google AppsScript returned me the following error:

> Exception: Service Google Slides API has not been enabled for your Apps Script-managed Cloud Platform project. If you have recently turned on this advanced Google service, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and then retry.

I don't know what was happen. Yesterday, the Apps Script was running correctly.

Anyone can help me to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. "SlidesApp batchUpdate" does't make too much sense. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: This happened to me once I deployed the script as a library. Moreover, I duplicated the library, made sure it was associated with a Default GCP project, and in the GAS editor under "Services", I could not locate "Google Slides API". Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Google functionality is scoped to a Google [Project](https://cloud.google.com/docs/overview#projects).

Your Apps Script is associated with a Google Project. Any other Google services (APIs) that your Apps Script uses must be enabled in the same Project.

Replacing `[PROJECT]` with your Apps Script's Project, visit the following link that represents the Google Slides API:

`https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/slides.googleapis.com?project=[PROJECT]`

You can click the `ENABLE` button to enable the Google Slides API in the Project and thus for your Apps Script too.

> **NOTE** You either changed Projects or added/disabled Google Slides functionality to your Apps Script but this would not have worked yesterday.